# How to set children Width for DockPanel to 100% inside ComboxItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, dockpanel

```
<ComboBoxItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto">
     <DockPanel Background="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" LastChildFill="True" Width="Auto">
        <Label DockPanel.Dock="Left" Name="lbName" ></Label>
        <Image DockPanel.Dock="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="image" Source="/Test;component/Images/cross.jpg" Width="16" Height="16" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
        <Image DockPanel.Dock="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="image2" Source="/Test;component/Images/cross.jpg" Width="16" Height="16" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
    </DockPanel>
</ComboBoxItem>
```

Like you can see on image below `DockPanel`(marked red) doesn't take 100% width of `ComboboxItem`.

How to stretch `DockPanel` to size of `ComboboxItem` in XAML?

[image]

Comment: Is this just in the designer? When launching it seems fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out, that the content of the `ComboBoxItem` filled the entire space, only when an event [`SelectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) triggered.

Example:

**`XAML`**

```
<ComboBox Width="300"
          Height="30"
          SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged">

    <ComboBoxItem>Test</ComboBoxItem>

    <ComboBoxItem Name="comboBoxItem"
                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"                          
                  Width="Auto">

        <DockPanel Background="Red" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                   Width="Auto">                    
            ...
        </DockPanel>
    </ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

**`Code-behind`**

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(comboBoxItem.ActualWidth.ToString());
}
```

When you start the application `ActualWidth` of ComboBoxItem is zero, however when `SelectionChanged` event triggered value will be 298.

**`Workaround`**

For workaround add `ComboBoxItem` in begin, for example: `Select item` and set for ComboBox `SelectedIndex="0"` like this:

```
<ComboBox Width="300"
          Height="30"
          SelectedIndex="0">

    <ComboBoxItem>Select item</ComboBoxItem>
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not use the `DockPanel` for this kind of layout. Use a `Grid` instead:

```
<ComboBoxItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
           <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
           <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Column="0" Name="lbName" ></Label>
        <Image Grid.Column="1" Name="image" Source="/Test;component/Images/cross.jpg" Width="16" Height="16" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
        <Image Grid.Column="2" Name="image2" Source="/Test;component/Images/cross.jpg" Width="16" Height="16" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
    </Grid>
</ComboBoxItem>
```